# Efficiently filtering out 'None' items in a list comprehension in which a function is called

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, list-comprehension

I have a list comprehension that calls a function which potentially returns `None`.

```py
f = lambda x: x if x < 3 else None
l = [f(x) for x in [1,2,3,4]]   # [1, 2, None, None]
```

I'd like to have the list comprehension as above, without the `None` entries.

What's a more efficient way to do the following, without creating the additional overhead, and while retaining the efficiency of the list comprehension?

```py
filter(None, l)   # [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 75):

Add an `if` into your comprehension like:

```
l = [y for y in (f(x) for x in [1,2,3,4]) if y is not None]
```

By placing a [Generator Expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) inside the list comprehension you will only need to evaluate the function once.  In addition the generator expression is a generator so takes no extra intermediate storage.

#### Python 3.8+

As of Python 3.8 you can use an [Assignment Expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) `(:=)` (AKA: Named Expressions or the Walrus Operator) to avoid multiple evaluations of `f()` like:

```
l = [y for x in [1,2,3,4] if (y := f(x)) is not None]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's already mentioned by Stephen but changing `l` in the OP into a generator expression (`g` below) allows you to evaluate `f` only once without creating an unnecessary list in the middle.

```py
f = lambda x: x if x < 3 else None
l = [f(x) for x in [1,2,3,4]]            # <--- list       (inefficient)
g = (f(x) for x in [1,2,3,4])            # <--- generator  (efficient)
output = [x for x in g if x is not None]
```

You can use `filter()` on the generator too (for a solution closer to what OP had in mind):

```py
output = list(filter(None, g))
```

N.B. `filter(None, g)` will filter out all falsy values, so it will filter out 0; if you don't want to do that, then probably the list comprehension above is the cleaner solution.

#### Python>=3.9

[Since Python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#optimizations:%7E:text=Optimized%20the%20idiom,the%20outer%20scope.), creating a singleton list and looping over it has been optimized. So instead of using a generator expression (which may be exhausted by accident) or the walrus operator (which leaks the loop variable to the outer scope), you can create a nested loop where the second loop is over a singleton list:

```py
output = [y for x in [1,2,3,4] for y in [f(x)] if y is not None]
```

Simple timeit test (on Python 3.12) shows that this is actually slightly faster than the other options (including the one using the walrus operator).